# Sub resorce is not working in Jersey REST API framework

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey-2.0

I followed the below documents for implementing the Sub resource, but it won't works as expected.

https://docs.huihoo.com/jersey/2.13/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2280

Sample Code,

```java
    @Path("/")
    public class OrderInfo {

      @Path("/orders/{id}")
      public OrderDetails getOrderById(@PathParam("id") int orderId) {
          return new OrderDetails(orderId);
      }
    }

    public class OrderDetails {

      private final int id;

      public OrderDetails(int id) {
          this.id = id;
      }

      @GET
      public String getOrderDetails() {
          return "test order details for order id: " + id;
      }
    }
```

I cross-checked in the log file and didn't found any exceptions. When I hit the URL "https://localhost:8443/orders/10", the response is, "{}". Is anything I have missed this code? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you create a complete runnable example [like this one](https://gist.github.com/psamsotha/13fe79f0e572bbbec6ca486e4501fe5a) (using [Jersey Test Framework](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/test-framework.html)) that reproduces the problem? It will be much easier to figure out the problem if I'm able to reproduce it. I don't see anything in the code you posted that would cause the results you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

change like this and try to make the call again,you have to give some name to path parameter at class level.

```
 @Path("orders")
    public class OrderInfo {

      @Path("{id}")
      public OrderDetails getOrderById(@PathParam("id") int orderId) {
          return new OrderDetails(orderId);
      }
    }
```

Comment: I already tried like this. But it won't works. Always returns "{}"